# Puppet Duplicate declaration errors with virtual defines

Tags: puppet, users

I'm trying to use puppet to add all my users to a system and add all of them to a single group. However, I keep getting

```
 Error 400 on SERVER: Duplicate declaration: Group[users] is already declared 
 in file *filename*:17 cannot redeclare at *filename* on node *server*
```

If I change user to a variable name, like $title, it works fine. How can I do this with a static group name like 'user'? I'm using the below configuration:

**NOTE:** I might have typos below. I had to retype all this as the system I'm on doesn't have Internet access.

```
 define users::virtual ($uid, $realname, $password) {
   user { $title:
     ensure => 'present',
     uid => $uid,
     gid => $'users',
     shell => '/bin/bash',
     home => "/home/${title}",
     comment => $realname,
     password => $password,
     managehome => true,
     require => Group ['users'],
 }

   group { 'users':
     ensure => 'present',
     gid => 100,
   }

   file { "/home/${title}":
     ensure => directory,
     owner => $title,
     group => 'users',
     mode => 0700,
     require => [ User[$title], Group['users'] ],
   }
 }

 class users {
   @users::virtual { 'user1':
     uid => 510,
     realname = 'John Doe',
     password = cyphertext
   }

   @users::virtual { 'user2':
     uid => 511,
     realname = 'Jane Doe',
     password = cyphertext
   }
 }

 node 'server' {
   realize (Users::Virtual['user1']
   realize (Users::Virtual['user2']
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Group['users'] resource shouldn't be within the defined resource  `users::virtual`.  You can only create the group once.Move that out to a separate class.

```
   group { 'users':
     ensure => 'present',
     gid => 100,
   }
```

Comment: But if I do that, the Group['users'] dependency requirements aren't met anymore.

Comment: What?  I suggested you move it, not remove it.  If you move it to another class and include it, then it should work fine.

Comment: Ah, thanks. That worked. I moved it, as you initially suggested, but I didn't include it.